# CSS Set content to 100% of parent div using grid layout

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, css-grid

I have recently started using the Grid layout in CSS and I am trying to make the elements in one of the **grid areas** fill the whole area. It works to set the `width` to `100%` of the parent. But I have a really hard time getting the `height` of my `div` to be the same as the parent `div`. Here is some code to showcase my problem:

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh
}

.grid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [sidebar-col-start] 15% [sidebar-col-end content-col-start] auto [content-col-end];
  grid-template-rows: [sidebar-row-start content-row-start] auto [sidebar-row-end footer-row-start] 10% [footer-row-end];
}

.area {
  grid-column: content-col-start / content-col-end;
  grid-row: content-row-start / footer-row-start;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
  align-items: stretch;
}

.footer {
  grid-column: sidebar-col-start / content-col-end;
  grid-row: footer-row-start / footer-row-end;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4);
}

.sidebar {
  grid-column: sidebar-col-start / sidebar-col-end;
  grid-row: sidebar-row-start / sidebar-row-end;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="sidebar">
  </div>
  <div class="area">
    <div class="red">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Link to Codepen: https://codepen.io/Martin36/pen/ayyoxv

My question is: How do I make a `div` fill the whole parent (which is a grid area)? Or more specifically, how do I make the `height` of the **children** match the **parent's height**?

Comment: I found out about `-webkit-fill-available` and `-moz-available`, but that only makes it work for webkit browsers and firefox.

Comment: your codepen doesn't work for me, can anyone else confirm this?

Answer (score -1):

Set .red with a min-height of 100vh.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh
}

.grid {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [sidebar-col-start] 15% [sidebar-col-end content-col-start] auto [content-col-end];
  grid-template-rows: [sidebar-row-start content-row-start] auto [sidebar-row-end footer-row-start] 10% [footer-row-end];
}

.area {
  grid-column: content-col-start / content-col-end;
  grid-row: content-row-start / footer-row-start;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
  align-items: stretch;
}

.footer {
  grid-column: sidebar-col-start / content-col-end;
  grid-row: footer-row-start / footer-row-end;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4);
}

.sidebar {
  grid-column: sidebar-col-start / sidebar-col-end;
  grid-row: sidebar-row-start / sidebar-row-end;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="sidebar">
  </div>
  <div class="area">
    <div class="red">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That will set the height to 100% of the whole page's height. I wanted it to be 100% of the parent, which in this case is the `.area` class.